# How would one compile a program for the Coldfire toolchain?

Tags: c, linux, cross-compiling, toolchain, coldfire

I'm trying to compile a simple hello world application to be run on uCLinux (2.4) which is running on a board with a Freescale Coldfire (MCF5280C) processor...and I'm not quite sure what to do here.

I know I need to compile with the correct version/tools from Freescale to target this hardware, so I downloaded and installed the Coldfire tool chain and verified that one I have is for my target:

```
mike@linux-4puc:/usr/local/m68k-elf/bin> ./gcc -v
Reading specs from /usr/local/lib/gcc-lib/m68k-elf/2.95.3/specs
gcc version 2.95.3 20010315 (release)(ColdFire patches - 20010318 from http://fiddes.net/coldfire/)(uClinux XIP and shared lib patches from http://www.snapgear.com/)
```

I tried a simple `gcc "file"` type command:

```
mike@linux-4puc:/home/mike> /usr/local/m68k-elf/bin/gcc test.c
/usr/local/m68k-elf/bin/ld.real: cannot open crt0.o: No such file or directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Which does not work at all.. so it's clearly more complex that than. The output almost looks like it wants me to build the tool chain before I use it?? Anyone ever done this before? Not sure what I need to do or if I just need some flags.

Comment: gcc --sysroot=/usr/local/m68k-elf test.c

Comment: Just fyi, if this does work it probably means something is setup incorrectly since you shouldn't need to add a --sysroot argument. That being said, it's a good idea to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also try seeing if you have a command called `m68k-elf-gcc` or something along those lines. This is a common naming for cross-compilers.

As for your problem, it sounds like there is something wrong with your compiler setup. crt0.o is the object file that contains C-runtime setup code. The linker (what is actually giving the error) should know where this file is if setup properly.

When you installed you should have run `make install` as the last step without having modified anything since the `make` step. The configuration step will setup certain variables and such based on the path where it's supposed to be installed.

Comment: Yup, that one is present as well, same version information is dumped and same issue running it. So perhaps you're correct about something being set up incorrectly.

Comment: @Mike Yeah, I doubted that it would solve your problem, it's just a bit easier to use (don't need to put the path in).

Comment: @Mike generally with gcc compilers you must either install all the components in the path they were built to live in, or you must provide a number of options to tell it where to find things such as libraries (and crt0.o, which is the initial entry point that sets up the call to `main()`). You may be able to find specifics from your hardware/tool vendor.

Comment: `m68k-elf-gcc` was the correct answer once it got all set up with proper options. Including `-m5282` for me

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get a FreeScale toolchain? I took a look at their site and it seemed only third parties supplied C++ cross-compilers. In the toolchain I get from NetBurner (for use with their hardware) the crt0.o file exists under the gcc-m68k\m68k-elf\lib directory.